# What are good options for data-only SIM and eSIM card options for Albania?

Tags: cellphones, data-plans, roaming, albania, macedonia

My friend and I are travelling to Albania soon. We want to avoid using our everyday UK SIM plans because the roaming costs are expensive.

I can use either an eSIM or a physical SIM. My friend, however, can only use a physical SIM; their phone does not support eSIMs.

I have been looking into a few different options but am confused as to what would be best. [Prepaid Data SIM Card Wiki](https://prepaid-data-sim-card.fandom.com/wiki/Albania) says that Vodafone and One Albania offer tourist packs, but we think these are overkill.

Really, we think we only need up to 5 GB because we are only staying for four days. We also do not need minutes or text messages as we plan to use apps like Messenger or WhatsApp.

We are going on a day trip to North Macedonia for one day, so if the eSIM/SIM also covers that country too then that would be great. Otherwise, we will do without for that trip.

#### eSIM

I found a few different providers and liked the pricing of [Maya Mobile](https://maya.net/) and [MobiMatter](https://mobimatter.com/), but have never used either of these before? Can anyone recommend these services?

#### Physical SIM

I saw that we can pick physical SIMs up from Vodafone or One Albania stores. However, is it possible to order one before we arrive in Albania so that we can set it up ready?

Also, does anyone know if it is possible for tourists to use other packages? For example, One Albania have a [Daily Internet package (1 GB for 200 ALL per day)](https://www.one.al/en/eshop/details/addon/PAKETA_TE_TJERA/PRD0701289) - is this something we could use instead of the tourist packs?

Comment: You might review the Albania article in [Too Many Adapters](https://toomanyadapters.com/buying-sim-card-albania/).